# Java - Instantiating generic typed class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types, instance

I have a class for example

```
public class Example<T> {...}
```

I would like to instantiate class Example with a specific type class which I know. Pseudocode would look something like that

```
public Example<T> createTypedExample(Class exampleClass, Class typeClass) {
  exampleClass.newInstance(typeClass); // made-up
}
```

So that this would give me same result

```
Example<String> ex = new Example<String>();
ex = createTypedExample(Example.class, String.class);
```

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: @VirtualTroll he wants to pass it as a type parameter. Not invoke constructor on it.

Comment: I actually think it's not possible. Java does generic stuff at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the return type i.e. the class of the new instance is fixed; there's no need to pass it to the method. Instead, add a `static` factory method to your `Example` class as

```
public class Example<T> {

    private T data;

    static <T> Example<T> newTypedExample(Class<T> type) {
        return new Example<T>();
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now, here's how you would create generic `Example` instances.

```
// String
Example<String> strTypedExample = Example.newTypedExample(String.class);

strTypedExample.setData("String Data");
System.out.println(strTypedExample.getData()); // String Data

// Integer
Example<Integer> intTypedExample = Example.newTypedExample(Integer.class);

intTypedExample.setData(123);
System.out.println(intTypedExample.getData()); // 123
```